# MongoDB Atlas connectivity with Node does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect and run Node.js server and connect to collection on MongoDB Atlas. Howewer, I am geting crash in line where I should get connection response. Please advise:

[image: Node]

**.env file:**

```
 MOVIEREVIEWS_DATABASE_URI=mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.wvtv6.mongodb.net/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority
MOVIEREVIEWS_NS=sample_mflix
```

---

**Index.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import MoviesRoute from './api/MoviesRoute.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongodb from 'mongodb';


class Index {
    static app = express();
    static router = express.Router();
    static main() {
        dotenv.config();
        Index.setUpServer();
        Index.setUpDatabase();
    }

    static setUpServer() {
        Index.app.use(cors());
        Index.app.use(express.json());
        Index.app.use('/api/v1/movies', 
        MoviesRoute.configRoutes(Index.router));
        Index.app.use('*', (req, res) => { res.status(404).json({ error: 'not found' }); });
    }

    static async setUpDatabase() {
        const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI);
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
        try { // Connect to the MongoDB cluster 
            await client.connect();
            Index.app.listen(port, () => {
                console.log(`server is running on port:${port}`);
    
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
             console.error(e); process.exit(1); }
    }
}
Index.main();
```

I cannot figure out what is missing :(

Comment: In your `.env` file you named your variable `MOVIEREVIEWS_DATABASE_URI` But you are referring to it as `process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI`. they should be the same. Am I right?

Comment: Thank You ! You have a good eye :)